# Kendo Grid: Drag Drop scrolls to top after drop

Tags: javascript, scroll, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-draggable

I implemented drag&drop for a grid like this:

```
var mainGrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: mainDataSource,
    columns: ["id", "name", "phone"],
    scrollable: true,
    editable: true,
    navigatable: true,
    height: 200
}).data("kendoGrid");

mainGrid.table.kendoDropTarget({
    group: "gridGroup",
    drop: function (e) {

        var draggedRows = e.draggable.hint.find("tr");
        e.draggable.hint.hide();
        var dropLocation = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)),
            dropGridRecord = mainDataSource.getByUid(dropLocation.parent().attr("data-uid"))
            if (dropLocation.is("th")) {
                return;
            }

        var beginningRangePosition = mainDataSource.indexOf(dropGridRecord), //beginning of the range of dropped row(s)
            rangeLimit = mainDataSource.indexOf(mainDataSource.getByUid(draggedRows.first().attr("data-uid"))); //start of the range of where the rows were dragged from


        //if dragging up, get the end of the range instead of the start
        if (rangeLimit > beginningRangePosition) {
            draggedRows.reverse(); //reverse the records so that as they are being placed, they come out in the correct order
        }

        //assign new spot in the main grid to each dragged row
        draggedRows.each(function () {
            var thisUid = $(this).attr("data-uid"),
                itemToMove = mainDataSource.getByUid(thisUid);
            mainDataSource.remove(itemToMove);
            mainDataSource.insert(beginningRangePosition, itemToMove);
        });


        //set the main grid moved rows to be dirty
        draggedRows.each(function () {
            var thisUid = $(this).attr("data-uid");
            mainDataSource.getByUid(thisUid).set("dirty", true);
        });

        //remark things as visibly dirty
        var dirtyItems = $.grep(mainDataSource.view(), function (e) {
            return e.dirty === true;
        });
        for (var a = 0; a < dirtyItems.length; a++) {
            var thisItem = dirtyItems[a];
            mainGrid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + thisItem.get("uid") + "']").find("td:eq(0)").addClass("k-dirty-cell");
            mainGrid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + thisItem.get("uid") + "']").find("td:eq(0)").prepend('<span class="k-dirty"></span>')
        };
    }
});
```

JS Fiddle: `jsfiddle.net/yagamilight1987/R2EyW/`

Scroll down to the last record. Drag and drop the last record to the previous position. The drop works but it scrolls to the top of the grid.

Comment: do you need more help with this or is the problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly working on my project i think there are some script issue

**Script that use**

```
<script src="~/Script/Jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/kendo.all.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/kendo.web.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="~/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**View**

```
<div id="grid">
</div>
```

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.fn.reverse = [].reverse; //save a new function from Array.reverse

        var data = [{
            id: 1,
            name: "Michael",
            phone: "897-894-8956"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "George Michael",
            phone: "897-555-5555"
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "George Sr.",
            phone: "897-444-4444"
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: "Gob",
            phone: "897-333-3333"
        }, {
            id: 5,
            name: "Lucille",
            phone: "897-222-2222"
        }, {
            id: 6,
            name: "Tobias",
            phone: "897-111-1111"
        }, {
            id: 7,
            name: "Maeby",
            phone: "897-666-6666"
        }, {
            id: 8,
            name: "Buster",
            phone: "897-777-7777"
        }, {
            id: 9,
            name: "Lindsay",
            phone: "897-888-8888"
        }];

        var dataModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                id: {
                    type: "number",
                    editable: false
                },
                name: {
                    type: "string",
                    editable: true
                },
                phone: {
                    type: "string",
                    editable: false
                }
            }
        });

        var mainDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            schema: {
                model: dataModel
            },
            data: data
        });

        var mainGrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: mainDataSource,
            columns: ["id", "name", "phone"],
            scrollable: true,
            editable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            height: 200
        }).data("kendoGrid");

        var selectedClass = 'k-state-selected';
        $(document).on('click', '#grid tbody tr', function (e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
                $(this).toggleClass(selectedClass);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass(selectedClass).siblings().removeClass(selectedClass);
            }
        });

        mainGrid.table.kendoDraggable({
            filter: "tbody tr",
            group: "gridGroup",
            axis: "y",
            hint: function (item) {
                var helper = $('<div class="k-grid k-widget drag-helper"/>');
                if (!item.hasClass(selectedClass)) {
                    item.addClass(selectedClass).siblings().removeClass(selectedClass);
                }
                var elements = item.parent().children('.' + selectedClass).clone();
                item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.' + selectedClass).remove();
                return helper.append(elements);
            }
        });

        mainGrid.table.kendoDropTarget({
            group: "gridGroup",
            drop: function (e) {

                var draggedRows = e.draggable.hint.find("tr");
                e.draggable.hint.hide();
                var dropLocation = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)),
            dropGridRecord = mainDataSource.getByUid(dropLocation.parent().attr("data-uid"))
                if (dropLocation.is("th")) {
                    return;
                }

                var beginningRangePosition = mainDataSource.indexOf(dropGridRecord), //beginning of the range of dropped row(s)
            rangeLimit = mainDataSource.indexOf(mainDataSource.getByUid(draggedRows.first().attr("data-uid"))); //start of the range of where the rows were dragged from


                //if dragging up, get the end of the range instead of the start
                if (rangeLimit > beginningRangePosition) {
                    draggedRows.reverse(); //reverse the records so that as they are being placed, they come out in the correct order
                }

                //assign new spot in the main grid to each dragged row
                draggedRows.each(function () {
                    var thisUid = $(this).attr("data-uid"),
                itemToMove = mainDataSource.getByUid(thisUid);
                    mainDataSource.remove(itemToMove);
                    mainDataSource.insert(beginningRangePosition, itemToMove);
                });


                //set the main grid moved rows to be dirty
                draggedRows.each(function () {
                    var thisUid = $(this).attr("data-uid");
                    mainDataSource.getByUid(thisUid).set("dirty", true);
                });

                //remark things as visibly dirty
                var dirtyItems = $.grep(mainDataSource.view(), function (e) {
                    return e.dirty === true;
                });
                for (var a = 0; a < dirtyItems.length; a++) {
                    var thisItem = dirtyItems[a];
                    mainGrid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + thisItem.get("uid") + "']").find("td:eq(0)").addClass("k-dirty-cell");
                    mainGrid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + thisItem.get("uid") + "']").find("td:eq(0)").prepend('<span class="k-dirty"></span>')
                };
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the data source which causes the grid to refresh, and the grid will unfortunately not remember its scroll position when you use the `navigatable` configuration option. You can fix that by remembering the position and restoring it manually:

```
    // remember scroll position before you start modifying the data source
    var gridContentDiv = $("#grid").find(".k-grid-content").first();
    var scrollTop =  gridContentDiv.scrollTop();

    // ...

    // restore scroll position when your modifications are done ...
    gridContentDiv.scrollTop(scrollTop);
```

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/R2EyW/6/))